# dxDataGrid : Compare Datasource Datagrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datagrid, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I want to combine the existing datafield in one grid to grid to get into the field and visible columns . 
But I need a datasource that comparison of the first grid when datafield that I choose to use Advantage Database Server to appear in the first grid CUSTUMERS , Brand , and INV Number and for the second grid is datafield remaining that date , period , etc .

How do I add if to compare it to a DataGrid can select according to the selected column . ?

Thanks . Regards Oki Saputra

[PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F92ms.png)

```js
   <script>
       
       
        function getData() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DoCollectDataMaster/Home")',
                dataType: "json"
            });
        }

        getData().done(function (data) { dataDetail = data; Execute(data); });
        var groupCellTemplate = function (groupCell, info) {
            $('<div>').html(info.text).css('font-style', '').appendTo(groupCell);
        };
        var headerCellTemplate = function (headCell, info) {
            $('<div>').html(info.column.caption).css('text-align', 'center').appendTo(headCell);
        };


        function getGroupedColumnCount() {
            var gridInstance = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid('instance');
            var colCount = gridInstance.columnCount();
            var groupColCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                groupColCount += (gridInstance.columnOption(i, 'groupIndex') !== undefined ? 1 : 0);
            return groupColCount;
        }

        function Execute(gridDataSource) {
            var hasCreated = false;
            var theGrid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
                dataSource: gridDataSource,
                columnFixing: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                grouping: {
                    autoExpandAll: false
                },

                columnAutoWidth: true,
                height:'40%',
                onContentReady: function (e) {
                    var groupCount = getGroupedColumnCount();
                    var gi = 0; var filter = false; var multi = false;
                    var btnCustom = $('<div>').dxButton({
                        icon: 'preferences',
                        onClick: function () {
                            PopUp.dxPopup("instance").show();
                        }
                    }).attr('title', 'Customize columns');
                    var btnCollapseAll = $('<div>').dxButton({
                        icon: 'overflow',
                        onClick: function () {
                            gi = gi - 1;
                            if (gi <= 0) { gi = 0; }
                            $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid('instance').collapseAll(gi);
                        }
                    }).attr('title', 'Collapse All');
                    var btnExpandAll = $('<div>').dxButton({
                        icon: 'menu',
                        onClick: function () {
                            $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid('instance').expandAll(gi);
                            gi = gi + 1;
                            if (gi >= groupCount) { gi = groupCount; }
                        }
                    }).attr('title', 'Expand All');
                    var btnFilter = $('<div>').dxButton({
                        icon: 'filter',
                        onClick: function () {
                            filter = !filter;
                            var dataGrid = $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid({ filterRow: { visible: filter } });
                        }
                    }).attr('title', 'Filter');
                    var btnMulti = $('<div>').dxButton({
                        icon: 'check',
                        onClick: function () {
                            multi = !multi;
                            if (multi) {
                                var dataGrid = $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid({ selection: { mode: 'multiple' } });
                            } else {
                                var dataGrid = $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid({ selection: { mode: 'single' } });
                            }
                        }
                    }).attr('title', 'Multiple selection');
                    if (!hasCreated) { btnCustom.appendTo('.dx-datagrid-header-panel'); btnExpandAll.appendTo('.dx-datagrid-header-panel'); btnCollapseAll.appendTo('.dx-datagrid-header-panel'); btnFilter.appendTo('.dx-datagrid-header-panel'); btnMulti.appendTo('.dx-datagrid-header-panel'); hasCreated = true; }
                },
                columnChooser: {
                    enabled: true,
                    height: 180,
                    width: 400,
                    emptyPanelText: 'A place to hide the columns'
                },
                allowColumnResizing: true,
                onRowPrepared: function (e) {
                    if (e.rowType == 'data') {
                        e.rowElement.addClass('rowatas');
                    } if (e.rowType == 'header') {
                        e.rowElement.addClass('rowbawah');
                    }
                },
                customizeColumns: function (columns) {
                    $.each(columns, function (_, element) {
                        element.groupCellTemplate = groupCellTemplate;
                        element.headerCellTemplate = headerCellTemplate;
                    });
                },

                showColumnLines: true,
                showRowLines: true,
                rowAlternationEnabled: true,
                showBorders: true,
                columns: [
                     
                     { dataField: 'customernm', caption: 'CUSTOMERS' },
                     { dataField: 'brandnm', caption: 'BRAND' },
                     { dataField: 'evdno', caption: 'INV NUMBER' },
                     { dataField: 'date', caption: 'DATE', dataType: 'date', format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' },
                     { dataField: 'period', caption: 'PERIOD', dataType: 'date', format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' },
                     { dataField: 'received', caption: 'RECIEVED', dataType: 'date', format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' },
                     { dataField: 'duedate', caption: 'DUEDATE', dataType: 'date', format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' },
                     { dataField: 'yourreff', caption: 'YOURREFF', },
                     { dataField: 'ourreff', caption: 'OURREFF' },
                     { dataField: 'nett', caption: 'NETT', format: "fixedPoint", },
                     { dataField: 'fee', caption: 'FEE', format: "fixedPoint", },
                     { dataField: 'vat', caption: 'VAT', format: "fixedPoint", },
                     { dataField: 'adtax', caption: 'ADTAX', format: "fixedPoint", },
                     { dataField: 'others', caption: 'OTHERS', format: "fixedPoint", },
                     { dataField: 'amount', caption: 'AMOUNT', format: "fixedPoint" },



                ],
                "export": {
                    enabled: true,
                    fileName: "RP_15",
                    exclude: "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Content/oki.css' />"

                },

                paging: {
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                sorting: {
                    mode: "multiple"
                },
                filterRow: {
                    visible: true
                },
                groupPanel:{
                    visible:true
                },
                searchPanel: {
                    visible: true,
                    placeholder: "Search"

                },

            });

            var source = [];
            var gridCols = theGrid.dxDataGrid("instance");
            for (i = 0; i <= gridCols.columnCount() - 1; i++) {
                source.push({ "field": gridCols.columnOption(i).dataField, "caption": gridCols.columnOption(i).caption, "width": gridCols.columnOption(i).width, "visible": gridCols.columnOption(i).visible, "filter": false });
            };
            var dxCols = $("#gridCols").dxDataGrid({
                dataSource: source,
                editing: { mode:'cell', allowUpdating: true },
                columns: [{ dataField: "field", caption: "Field", visible: false, allowEditing: false },
                    { dataField: "caption", caption: "Columns", allowEditing: false },
                    { dataField: "visible", caption: "Visible", width: 80, dataType: "boolean" },
                ],
                selection: { mode: 'single' },
                columnAutoWidth: true,
                scrolling: { mode: "virtual" },
                paging: { pageSize: 5 },
                onSelectionChanged: function (selItems) { var data = selItems.currentSelectedRowKeys[0]; alert(data); },
                onCellClick: function (clickedCell) {
                    if (clickedCell.column.dataField == "visible") {
                        var gc1 = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid("instance");
                        var gc2 = $("#gridCols").dxDataGrid("instance");
                        gc1.columnOption(gc2.cellValue(clickedCell.rowIndex, "field"), "visible", clickedCell.value);
                        //alert(clickedCell.rowIndex);
                        //alert(gc2.cellValue(clickedCell.rowIndex, "field"));
                        //alert(clickedCell.value);
                    }
                },
                onRowClick: function () { alert("rowclicked");},
                customizeColumns: function (columns) {
                    $.each(columns, function (_, element) {
                        element.headerCellTemplate = headerCellTemplate;
                    });
                }
            });

            var sourceAV = [];
            var gridAvail = theGrid.dxDataGrid("instance");
            for (i = 0; i <= gridAvail.columnCount() - 1; i++) {
                sourceAV.push({ "field": gridAvail.columnOption(i).dataField, "caption": gridAvail.columnOption(i).caption, "width": gridAvail.columnOption(i).width, "visible": gridAvail.columnOption(i).visible, "filter": false });
                
            };
            var dxAvail = $("#gridAvail").dxDataGrid({
                dataSource: sourceAV,
                editing: { mode: 'cell', allowUpdating: true },
                columns: [{ dataField: "field", caption: "Field", visible: false, allowEditing: false },
                    { dataField: "caption", caption: "Columns", allowEditing: false },
                    { dataField: "visible", caption: "Visible", width: 80, dataType: "boolean" },
                ],
                selection: { mode: 'single' },
                columnAutoWidth: true,
                scrolling: { mode: "virtual" },
                paging: { pageSize: 5 },
                onSelectionChanged: function (selItems) { var data = selItems.currentSelectedRowKeys[0]; alert(data); },
                onCellClick: function (clickedCell) {
                    if (clickedCell.column.dataField == "visible") {
                        var gc1 = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid("instance");
                        var gc2 = $("#gridAvail").dxDataGrid("instance");
                        gc1.columnOption(gc2.cellValue(clickedCell.rowIndex, "field"), "visible", clickedCell.value);
                        //alert(clickedCell.rowIndex);
                        //alert(gc2.cellValue(clickedCell.rowIndex, "field"));
                        //alert(clickedCell.value);
                    }
                },
                onRowClick: function () { alert("rowclicked"); },
                customizeColumns: function (columns) {
                    $.each(columns, function (_, element) {
                        element.headerCellTemplate = headerCellTemplate;
                    });
                }
            });
          
            //
            var panelItems = [{ title: "Column", itemTitleTemplate: "X1", contentTemplate: $("#gridCols") },
                              { title: "Available", itemTitleTemplate: "X2", contentTemplate: $("#gridAvail") }];
            var tabCreated = null;
            var PopUp = $("#customizecolumn").dxPopup({
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                showTitle: true,
                title: "Customize column",
                visible: false,
                dragEnabled: true,
                closeOnOutsideClick: false,
                onShowing: function () {
                    if (!tabCreated) {
                        tabCreated = $("#customtab").dxTabPanel({
                            items: panelItems,
                            itemTemplate: function (item) { return item.contentTemplate },
                            selectedIndex: 0,
                            swipeEnabled: true,
                            loop: true,
                            animationEnabled: true
                            //visible: false
                        }).dxTabPanel("instance");
                    }
                    //tabCreated.repaint();
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

```html
<div id="customizecolumn">
        <div id="customtab">
            <div id="gridCols" style="height: 200px; width: 100%"></div>
            <div id="gridAvail" style="height: 200px; width: 100%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gridContainer" style="height: 700px; width: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to check if a dataSource contains some field, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I do. You're right sergey.

Comment: Well, just check the loaded data source items. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su2cubw6/2/).